# Bare Bulb diffuser for travel?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, flash, travel

I found the thread for diffuser for speedlights [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65495/diffuser-for-travelling) but wanted to check out options available for bare-bulb flashes, specifically the Godox AD360ii.

I'll be traveling to Vietnam for 3 weeks in December 2016 - Jan 2017, and plan to backpack from the North to the South by motorbike/bus/train. I'd like to see what options are available for portable setups, but I'd be willing to sacrifice carrying additional weight if the diffuser is way better. I'll also have a nano-manfrotto light stand attached to the side of the pack.

The [Westscott LunaGrip](http://kubotaimagetools.com/products/westcott-lunagrip-designed-by-kevin-kubota) looks really promising, and I believe I can jimmy rig something to make the bare bulb flash fit in that mounting bracket.

Quality of light is very important to me, so ideally I'd want as soft light as I can produce.

In case you were asking, why bare bulb vs speedlights: I want the output to be able to overpower the sun, as well as easier HSS capabilities (I hate fiddling with ND filters, especially for travel). Currently my solution would be the Westcott collapsible umbrella but would love something with a bit more efficiency. A collapsible beauty dish looks promising as well, but wasn't sure if there were way better solutions.

Some uses for flash will be for editorial type portrait work in remote-areas I can get to by bike. I'll be using a 40L bag equivalent, or the Thule Covert for my main travels.

Wasn't sure if this was necessary, but for reference, I will be bringing the Sony A7RII, 24-70L II, 50L, 16-35L II, Ricoh GR.

I'd greatly appreciate any recommendations or insight from other experienced travel photographers. Thanks. (And yes I am aware my pack will be majority camera gear. Again, portrait and landscape work will be a priority)

Comment: As this was asked some time ago and never answered, I'm curious what you ended up using?

Answer (score 1):

I mount Godox AD200 on Bowens mount adapter (with a handle) and slide a 24"x24" Godox square softbox on the adapter. If you can manage to mount AD360ii on Bowens adapter, this solution might work.

[image]

If my camera is on a tripod, I can hold the softbox where I want and trigger my camera remotely alternately an assistant can hold the softbox while I shoot.

These softboxes are portable - you can fold them away (although they are somewhat clunky), don't have screws or need setup. Just unfold them and slide them on to the bowens adapter and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use a grip arm with a diffusion panel. And block/diffuse the sun, when possible, as opposed to overpowering it.  These items should not add weight or bulk to your pack.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above a white plastic bag is the choice to go with. best thing is different bags have different thicknesses. The thinner the bag more the light will pass through. Another trick is to tape a toothpick or plastic straw (Straw can be cut shorter to taste) to the flash's top and use cotton wadding in front of the flash.

Comment: A plastic bag can change the color of the light and does not diffuse the light beyond the tiny area of the front of the flash. Besides that it could end as unnecessary trash each time you use one.

Answer (score -2):

Ideas for you.

1. Put a kleenex or a handkerchief over the flash.
2. Easier to do: Put a white plastic bag over the flash.  Shopping bags come in various weights.  You would need to do some experimenting ahead of time.   A rubber band to keep it flat over the flash.  A white paper bag works too, but is heavier, and is less uniform.

These don't change the area of the light source for true diffusion, but will scatter more light sideways to where it bounces once before hitting the target. The net effect is that shadows are filled somewhat.  This doesn't work very well in a wide space, as most of the bounce will be from the ground which has odd effects.

3. The flash has up/down swivel capability.  Bounce the light off the ceiling.
4. Not clear if this model can pivot sideways.  If not, then get a cable to run from the hotshoe to the flash.  Or get a remote.  This allows you to bounce off of the wall.
5. Put a clip on the rim of the flash that can hold a grey card at a 45 degree angle. Aim the flash straight up, and bounce off the card. Most grey cards are white on the back side.  Doesn't even have to be a real grey card.  And piece of card stock will work.  Depending on the finish you can get more or less diffuse light.  By using different colours of card you can either tint the light to enhance or correct.  (E.g. if you are shooting things lit by candles, use a yellow card.  If firelight, use an orange card) (For firelight, try to bounce the light off the ground.)
6. If you curve the card so that it's a convex surface toward the flash, you can in effect widen the scatter which will pick up more room reflections.

Comment: 1. Adding a kleenex on a flash will not work. Diffuse light is about the total area of the light source, not the "texture" in front of it. 2. Random plastic bags will probably change the color of the light. You can see a plastic as white, but it can have a magenta or other colors. But also it gives no advantage. The same with a small card. The only viable tip is the bouncing. But the user is asking for a specific opinion on large diffusers.

Comment: Think what you want.  I've have actually used all of these techniques to good effect.  I saw the specific request, but also saw 'bare bulb' and 'travel' and a long time since it had been asked.  I figured that a 'makeshift, not quite on topic' answer may help another traveler. Thank you for putting the explanation for your downvote. Many people don't take the time to do that.

Comment: Yes, I think it is important to explain. Actually, the feedback is for everyone. I will try to make samples of this comments :o)